# highcharts line for one point serie

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When having a graph with one serie and that serie has one point, the point is centered to the graph. When I have a sparkline the point is almost invisible. So were I am looking for, is a dotted or dashed line to the centered point, without a x-value. [See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWViI.png)

Comment: seem like you want plotLine at the center, use plotLine give exact value and style it as dashed

Comment: I have tried that, but a plotline uses the whole width. I want a line that stops at the central point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could: add a dummy point before the original data point in series data, set xAxis `min` to a value of the real point and set `dashStyle` of your series.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dfe9cj4u/

Comment: This looks like a solution. But what happens if you're using datetime values on the xAxis?

Comment: Either way, you're setting an x axis value. If you're using a datetime axis, you need to select an appropriate datetime value for the first point (or, use pointStart and pointInterval)